# Android Realm Migration Issue → java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Primary key field 'foo' cannot be changed after object was created

Tags: android, realm, realm-migration

During a Realm migration on Android, I am attempting to uppercase an existing String field but getting the following error because the field is a primary key.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Primary key field 'foo' cannot be changed after object was created.
```

The following is my existing code.

```
schema.get("FooEntity")
        .transform(entity -> {
                final String fieldValue = entity.getString("foo");
                entity.setString("foo", fieldValue.toUpperCase(Locale.US));
        });
```

My approach to rectify the migration issue is to: first remove the primary key; then transform the field value; and finally re-add the primary key.

```
schema.get("FooEntity")
    .removePrimaryKey()
    .transform(entity -> {
            final String fieldValue = entity.getString("foo");
            entity.setString("foo", fieldValue.toUpperCase(Locale.US));
    })
    .addPrimaryKey("foo");
```

This seems to work as expected.

Are there any issues associated with this approach?

Comment: afaik you cannot edit primary keys in realm in any way without deleting the object and re-adding it. one problem might be that the "update" will appear as a deletion in any attached listeners. however this is only an issue in a production DB where you can't afford deletions of data like that

Comment: Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40999736/7708305) answer. I think it will answer your question.

Comment: @KaranHarshWardhan first, this approach seems to work -- the Exception is no longer thrown.  second, this is in a migration at app startup, so there are no listeners.

Comment: @PratikKulkarni yes, i saw that answer.  that is generally what i would plan as an alternative; however, the approach i presented seems to work, so i was curious if anyone saw any downsides to this as it is arguably more straightforward.